# Customize formview paging text

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

Ultimately, I am trying to change the paging text (1 2 3 etc) to the year of each record returned. (2010 2011 2012).

I've entered the code on both the databound PreRender event. I can get it to loop fine until I change the PageIndex to grab the Label's value that holds the year, at which time I get this error: Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.

ASPX

```
  <asp:FormView ID="fvRptHeader" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsRptHeader"
         AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="ReportId" HeaderText="Annual Reports"
         OnDataBound="fvRptHeader_DataBound" OnPreRender="fvRptHeader_PreRender">
         <PagerTemplate>
             //TODO: Figure out the linking
             <a href="#"><asp:Label ID="lbl_pageNum" runat="server" /></a>
         </PagerTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         ....Code
         </itemTemplate>
  </formview>
```

ASPX.CS

```
  protected void fvRptHeader_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormViewRow pagerRow = fvRptHeader.TopPagerRow;
        Label pageNum = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("lbl_pageNum");

        if (pageNum != null)
        {
            string s_rowValue = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < fvRptHeader.PageCount; i++)
            {
                fvRptHeader.PageIndex = i; //Gives Error: Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.
                Label lbl_year = (Label)fvRptHeader.Row.FindControl("lblRptYearDescription");
                s_rowValue += lbl_year.Text + i.ToString();
            }
            pageNum.Text = s_rowValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try fvRptHeader.SetPageIndex(i); instead.

Comment: Great suggestion Kiran, however it still threw the same error.